Determining equation for parabola in complex projective space
I am reading about complex projective spaces; in one section, the author states that the parabola "$y = x^2$ in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ can be expressed as $zy = x^2$" (if I am understanding it correctly):

However, I am unable to see why that is true. My attempt:

If a point $(x' : y' : z')$ lies on $y = x^2$, there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the point $(\lambda x', \lambda y', \lambda z')$ lies on $y = x^2$, i.e. $y' = \lambda x'^2$.

Any insight would be hugely appreciated :)

Have you come across the operation of homogenization, which amounts in your situation to taking a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ and multiplying each monomial term by the smallest power of $z$ that makes all the terms of the same total degree? That's what's happening here; geometrically it amounts to embedding the $(x, y)$-plane as the affine plane $(x, y, 1)$. There are a few more details here (for non-mathematicians), including pictures: https://diffgeom.com/blogs/about-math/projective-geometry

Where is this excerpt from? The author is being sloppy with the notation and using the same variables to denote different things. One might phrase this more carefully by saying: consider the affine plane $\mathbb{C}^2$ with coordinates $x,y$ and the projective plane $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ with projective coordinates $X,Y,Z$. We can consider $\mathbb{C}^2$ as the affine open set $U$ where $Z \neq 0$; on this set, the affine coordinates are $x = X/Z, y = Y/Z$. If we take the parabola $y = x^2$ in $U$, its closure in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ is cut out by $YZ = X^2$.

 You can consider the situation in ${\Bbb A}^3$ as the cone $yz-x^2=0$ through the origin, and a plane $y-z=0$ through the origin. To get back the affine plane intersect with and look in $z=1$.
In this case the plane $y=z$ ($y=1$) intersects $yz-x^2=0$ ($y=x^2$) in the line pair $(x-z)(x+z)=0$ (or points $x=\pm 1$).
